# WooCommerce: Use of the Product Categories shortcode

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the woocommerce plugin for a wordpress site. 
This shortcode display the name AND the number of products on every listed category.

```
[product_categories orderby="name" order="ASC" columns="4" ids="16,17,14,15,18,22,23,24,25,29,30"]
```

I need to show ONLY the name, and discard the number of products inside every category.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery for hidding the Count.

Just add the code : `jQuery('h3 .count').hide();` in the js file which is called on this page.

The result is as follows:

**Previous:**

[image]

**Now:**

[image]